# Redis - can you query based on values?

Tags: redis, filtering

I am using Redis 5.x

Is it possible to query based on Values (not Keys)?

(e.g. perform filtering)

Answer (score 3):

No - Redis does not perform searches based on values. For that you'll need to index the data yourself as described in https://redis.io/topics/indexes or use something like [RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/).